# Shopify border selected color

Tags: shopify, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I have shopify shop and i found a code on internet to replace the color by his image [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9SAK.png).

I really need to add a border when the color is selected, can someone help me please.

the code is to do this is  :

```
{%if option.name == "Couleur"%}
  <label>{{option.name}}</label>
  {%assign index = forloop.index %}
  {%for value in option.values%}
    <input class="single-option-selector-{{ section.id }}" id="Couleur-{{forloop.index}}" type="radio" style='visibility:hidden;display:none' name="Couleur" value="{{ value | escape }}" data-index="option{{index}}" {% if option.selected_value == value %}checked{%endif%}/>
    <label id="colorSelected" class="label_couleur" for="Couleur-{{forloop.index}}" style="margin: 0 5px;">
      <img class="img_couleur"  src="{{value | escape | append:'.jpg' | strip | asset_url }}"/>      
    </label>
  {%endfor%}
{%else%}
```

I really need help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference in the Shopify community forum, provided a solution to create swatch images for color in products. Please click [here](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Product-pages-Add-color-swatches-to-products/td-p/616427) to check to achieve.

This solution will not work venture and boundless theme. I implement in debut theme is working for client store.